# hibernate restrictions.in with and, how to use?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have table like below

```
id, employee_no, survey_no, name
1    test          1         test_name
2    test2         1         test_name2
3    test3         1         test_name3
4    test4         2         test_name4
```

how to query with Restriction.in by combining below AND into one IN statement?

```
 IN[   (if(survey_no==1)  && employee_no== 'test')  ,  
       (if(survey_no==1)  && employee_no== 'test2') ,
        ...
   ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the criteria combination you want to use (btw. it is easier to help with the Hibernate entity bean definition instead of the table structure):

```
String[] employeeNames = { "test", "test2" };
List<Survey> surveys = getSession().createCriteria(Survey.class).add(
        Restrictions.and
        (
            Restrictions.eq("surveyNumber", 1),
            Restrictions.in("employeeName", employeeNames)
        )
    ).list();
```

Comment: Restrictions are added to the criteria as AND clauses by default. In this case the code is correct, but would be simpler if the two restrictions were added directly to the criteria instead of nested in a Restrictions.and statement.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. Seems as if I then made some queries more complicated than they actually needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<EmployeeSurvey> employeeSurvey = getSession().createCriteria
(EmployeeSurvey.class).add(
    Restrictions.and
    (
        Restrictions.eq("survey_no", 1), 
        Restrictions.in("employee_name", new String[] {"test", "test1"})
    )).list();
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You should explain why this piece of code is a solution for the described problem.