# JPA CriteriaQuery - How to use IN comparison operator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, predicate

I have two java objects.

1. User(every user has an index column)
2. Address( every address has an `user_index` column too)

I have a List of all the users index list, `usersIndexList` as given input and I want to fetch all of the address objects based on this `usersIndexList`. I found an example on another thread. And tried to follow it but it does not work.

[JPA CriteriaBuilder - How to use "IN" comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321916/jpa-criteriabuilder-how-to-use-in-comparison-operator)

My code:

```
List<String> usersIndexList= new ArrayList<String> ();
for (User u : usersList) {
    usersIndexList.add(u.getIndex());
}

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> subQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> fromUser= subQuery.from(User.class);

    Expression<String> exp = fromUser.get("user_index");
    Predicate predicate = exp.in(usersIndexList);

    subQuery.where(predicate);

    TypedQuery<User> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(subQuery);

    return query.getResultList();
```

But this query is not returning the desired result :(

Can someone please tell me, where I am doing wrong or give me an alternate solutions if its possible via `nativequery` or `namedquery` or any other way

Comment: For the answer refer the link <https://stackoverflow.com/a/2719773/9725064>

Comment: For the answer refer the link [IN Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2719773/9725064)

Comment: your query formation is correct. Can you please explain what do you mean by `But this query is not returning the desired result`?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, *you want to fetch all of the **address objects** based on this `usersIndexList`*. But in your code you are selecting `User` objects, not the `Address`. Is my understanding Correct? If yes, then please change your root to `Address` as below -

```
List<String> usersIndexList= new ArrayList<String> ();
for (User u : usersList) {
    usersIndexList.add(u.getIndex());
}

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Address> subQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Address.class);
    Root<Address> fromAddress= subQuery.from(Address.class);

    Expression<String> exp = fromAddress.get("user_index");
    Predicate predicate = exp.in(usersIndexList);

    subQuery.where(predicate);

    TypedQuery<Address> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(subQuery);

    return query.getResultList();
```